# const in a base class vs static const in a derived class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization

Do you think there will be any difference between performance/memory utilization in the following two cases? Would a compiler optimize the first piece of code to not make any difference between the two.

```
class VersionBase 
{
public:
    VersionBase(int iVer) : m_iVersion(iVer) {…}; 
    int GetVersion() const { return m_iVersion; };
private:
    const int m_iVersion;                                     
}

class SomeVersionedDataObject : VersionBase 
{
    VersionedDataObject() : VersionBase(2) {…}; //  Set version to whatever is the latest for the class
    …
    …
}
```

vs

```
class SomeVersionedDataObject
{
public: 
    VersionedDataObject()
    int GetVersion() const { return m_iVersion; };
private:
    static const int m_iVersion = 2;
}
```

Comment: "Would a compiler optimize the first piece of code to not make any difference between the two." -- In some specially constructed tests, perhaps, but generally, why do you think that's even possible? They don't mean the same thing, and at the very least, anything that depends directly or indirectly on `sizeof(VersionBase)` will behave differently, and *any* use of `SomeVersionedDataObject` almost certainly qualifies as depending on `sizeof(VersionBase)`.

Comment: The point to note is that both are always initialized by a constant say '2' as in the code. So the question is would a compiler be smart enough to realize that m_iVersion is going to hold the same value for all copies of the object and so do some magic and not allocate memory for the variable in every copy of the object? (Reading this again i think I've gotten how compiler optimization works all wrong, but then there are no dumb questions!)

Comment: @NVM The compiler can't really work magic here. `sizeof(VersionBase)` has to be the same in the entire program, and nothing is preventing you from instantiating `VersionBase` directly, with many different values of `m_iVersion`. There's no way to move the `const int` out of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-static class member, even if `const`, has to be part of every object of the class. So the second definition will use less memory, assuming at least two instances are created.

**EDIT**

A solution with little memory usage and code duplicity would be as follows:

```
// In one header
template <int version>
class VersionBase
{
public:
  int GetVersion() const { return s_version; };
private:
  static const int s_version;
};

template <int version>
const int VersionBase::s_version = version;


// Anywhere, using the header above
class SomeVersionedDataObject : public VersionBase<2>
{
  :::
};
```

Comment: Assuming I will have tens of thousands of instances of 'SomeVersionedDataObject' and multiple classes deriving from VersionBase (always initialized by a constant value which is the same for all instances of a particular class) is there some way of designing this so that every object of a particular class does not allocate memory for the variable?

Comment: @NVM Yes, use the static const variable as in your second example.

Comment: Thanks but then that would be very ugly and un-maintainable ( I have hundreds of such classes). I'll have to repeat the same piece of code in all versioned classes. I know you've answered my question, just trying to see if there is way around this.

Comment: @NVM I've added a potential solution to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having myself dealt with serialization a fair bit, I settled on something different (and threw inheritance out of the window):

```
inline int version(SomeVersionedDataObject const&) { return 2; }
```

The memory footprint is equivalent to that of a `static int const version` case, except that the implementation of the `version` method is free to be a tad more clever (ie, you can have versions for polymorphic classes that dispatch to a `virtual` method, ...).

And of course, it's quite easy to provide a default version for those objects that do not need one yet:

```
int version(...) { return 0; }
```

I prefer it to encoding information in some base classes, because I can extend any class with it *without modifying the class itself*.

Comment: This is actually a brilliant idea. One of the problems I was thinking about was derived classes holding their own version number and inheritance would be an issue there. This would work great there.